# How to create a hierarchical system of permissions in the database?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, database-design, architecture

Example:

We have 'backend user' entity in database.

Backend user is the employee of shop or brand. Brand can have many shops.

If 'backend user' is employee of shop - he has access only to the records of this shop.

If 'backend user' is employee of brand - he has access to records of shops 
 which belong to this brand.

In future there will be other permission levels, like 'shop group'.

I want to build flexible scalable database shema for this case. Maybe you can recommend some literature or patterns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problem at one point and went with following solution (simplified for clarity):

[image]

Basically, it's vanilla RBAC model with additional layer of abstraction in form of "User Role" entity. Meaning, users don't "just" have roles, they have them in terms of one or several entities, e.g.:

- `User "John"` has `role "admin"` in terms of `entity "shop"`
- `User "John"` has `role "guest"` in terms of `entity "brand"`
- `User "Mary"` has `role "admin"` in terms of `entity "brand"`
- `User "Steven"` has `role "manager"` in terms of `entity "shop group"`

I'm not entirely sure that it's applicable in your case, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Now I don't know if this solution is good for me. We still work on the solution with team now with parallel communication with client. So, maybe your ideas will good for us, thanks!